# three column ordered list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

i have a list of categories that i'd like to show in 3 columns ordered by name.  I am using `ul` and `li` with css

```
li {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

so I can just loop through each categories.  This is working fine except for one issue, ordering.  I'd like the list ordered alphabetically but by column.  To demonstrate,  if I have 7 categories, A to G, it currently looks like

```
A  |  B  |  C
D  |  E  |  F
G  |
```

I'd like it to look like

```
A  |  D  |  G  
B  |  E  |
C  |  F  |
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: to render what order do you want? A B C or A D G?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to go over this.  Both involves grouping your list in 3 groups which can be achieved using `in_groups_of` but you need to pass the number of elements that should belong in the group

```
@categories = ('A'..'G').to_a

total_per_column = (@categories.size / 3.0).ceil
@categories = @categories.in_groups_of(3, false)
```

You need to pass `false` so it won't try to fill up the missing elements, ie the last group will only contain 'G'

Next are the two options:

1. use 3 `ul` that are floated left

   ```
   <% @categories.each do |categories| %>
     <ul>
      <% categories.each do |category| %>
        <li><%= category %></li>
      <% end %>
     </ul>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. or use some sort of logic like below

   ```
   <ul>
     <% total_per_column.times do |index| %>
       <% @categories.each do |categories| %>
         <% if category = categories[index] %>
           <li><%= category %></li>
         <% end %>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
   ```

I personally prefer the first one because it's simpler. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
xs = %w(a b c d e f g)
xs.in_groups(3).transpose
#=> [["a", "d", "g"], ["b", "e", nil], ["c", "f", nil]]
```

And now that the row elements are nicely placed, draw the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
@array = [A..Z]  
$i = 0
$j = 0 
    while $i < $array.count  do
     <ul>
       while $j < 3
      <li>
        puts @array[$i]
      </li>
        $j +=1
       end
       $i +=1
     </ul>
    end
```

Use this concept of nested while loop.